# Python Numpy append array without flattening

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, flatten

In Python 3 I am importing several data files in a loop, and I would like to be able to store all the data in a single 2-dimensional array. I start with something like `data = np.array([])` and on each iteration i want to add a new array `datai = np.array([1,2,3])`, how can I get my final array to look like this? `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],...,[1,2,3]]`

I have tried np.append, np.concatenate, and np.stack, but none seem to work. An example code that I'm trying:

```
data = np.array([])
for i in range(datalen):
    datai = *func to load data as array*
    data = np.append(data, datai)
```

but of course this returns a flattened array. Is there any way I can get back a 2-dimensional array of length `datalen` with each element being the array `datai`?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want `vstack`.  Are all of your subarrays the same length?

Comment: yes! Ok i can get that to work for all iterations after the first, but since I start with an empty array it gives me a dimension error. I can just throw in an if statement to save the first array and vstack from then forward, but is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Look at the `np.append` docs.  What does it say about omitting the `axis` parameter?

Comment: You are trying to use a list append model for arrays.  `np.empty([])` is not the same as the list `[]`.  Look at its `shape` and `ndim`.  For `concatenate` to work, the inputs have to have matching dimensions.  `data1` is 1d (3,).  It can be joined on axis 0 to another 1d array.  To join on a new initial axis it needs to be 2d (which is what `vstack` addresses).  In any case repeated list append is the right way, not a repeated concatenate.

Comment: What's the shape of `data1`?  How do you load it?  Often, when loaded from a txt file, the resulting array will be 2d.  It could of course be 1d.

Comment: is there an explanation of this insane behaviour anywhere? (the flattening that is)

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way would be vstack

```
data = np.vstack((get_data() for i in range(datalen)))
```

vstack requires a tuple/iterable

```
data = np.vstack((data1, data2, data3))
```

or you can do this by appending with axis=0

```
data = np.empty(shape=(0, 3))
data = np.append(data, datai.reshape((-1, 3)), axis=0)  # -1 will make the rows automatic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your array using np.reshape like this

`flattened_array = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])`

`wanted_array = np.reshape(flattened_array, (-1, 3))`

This would result in

`[[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: my way to solve it! It seems dirty though, no?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 using list comprehensions:

```
data = []
datalen = 4
datai = range(1,4)
data = [list(datai) for _ in range(datalen)]
print (data)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Solution 2 (just a bit lengthy)

```
data = []
datalen = 4

for i in range(datalen):
    datai = range(1,4)
    data.append(list(datai))
print (data)
```

with the same output as above. In the second method you can also just simply use `data.append(list(range(1,4)))`. You can choose if you want to convert `datai` to list or not. If you want the final output as an array, you can just use `np.array()`

Comment: method 2: why call `np.arange(1,4)` instead of `range(1,4)` when you're going to convert it to list anyway?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
data = np.zeros(shape=(datalen,len(datai))
for i in range(datalen):
   data[i] = datai
```

Comment: If you wish to do it using NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

It's called `numpy.tile`.

From the official docs:

```py
>>> c = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> np.tile(c,(3,1))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

so, for your `datai` do `np.tile(datai,(N_repeats,1))`